# Bootstrap tooltip, invert its function: display all and hide on hover

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, tooltip

I have a page with many tooltips and I want to display all at first.

They all have a "tooltipWarn" class.

```
<span class='warning tooltipWarn'>test</span>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.tooltipWarn').tooltip({
   placement: "bottom",
   title: 'blablabla'
});
$('.tooltipWarn').tooltip("show");
```

This works, and I want them to be hidden on hover. I've done that:

```
$('.tooltipWarn').hover(function(){
   $(this).tooltip('hide');
})
```

I wan't to close the tooltip when hovering the tooltip itself, not the text in

Answer (score 0):

Tooltip function generates the text in a DIV with "tooltip-inner" class.

So this code works:

```
$('.tooltip-inner').hover(function(){
   $(this).parent().tooltip('hide');
})
```